# Account locked due to 6 failed logins occurred when using expect script to call sftp to upload file

Tags: upload, sftp, expect, account, locked

I have written an expect script in which i call sftp to upload file and i pass sftpuser sftppass sftpip to the script. In shell, i call this script with same right parameter and it will upload file successfully five times. And in the sixth turn, it reports the following error:
Account locked due to 6 failed logins

I doubt that i have passed the right password every time, why system treat it as an failure login?

The expect script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set loginuser [lindex $argv 0]
set loginpass [lindex $argv 1]
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 2]
set remote_dir [lindex $argv 3]
set put_file [lindex $argv 4]
    
set timeout 300
set cmd_prompt "sftp>"


#-------------------------------------------------- login by ssh
spawn sftp $loginuser@$ipaddr
set timeout 300
expect {
-re "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" {
send "yes\r"
} -re "assword:" {
send "$loginpass\r"
} -re "Permission denied, please try again." {
exit
} -re "Connection refused" {
exit
} timeout {
exit
} eof {
exit
}
}

expect {
-re "assword:" {
send "$loginpass\r"
}
-re $cmd_prompt {
send "\r"
}
}

exec sleep 1
expect {
-re $cmd_prompt {
send "cd $remote_dir\r"
}
}

#exec sleep 1
#expect {
#-re $cmd_prompt {
#send "ls\r"
#}
#}

exec sleep 1
expect {
-re $cmd_prompt {
send "put $put_file\r"
}
}

expect {
-re $cmd_prompt {
send "exit\r"
}
}

expect eof
#interact
```

The command calling this script in shell looks like this:
./autoftp.sh sftpuser sftpuserpass 172.11.11.11 upload ./test.dat

Comment: Obviously, make sure you actually know the password for that user. Next, check that the expect script file does not use `\r\n` line endings.

Answer (score 1):

To see what exactly is going on, run expect with the `-d` debug flag and study the resulting output carefully.

A few other observations:

- All your expect patterns have the `-re` flag which means to treat them as regular expressions, but they are not actually regular expressions except for the first, where the question mark is going to be misinterpreted.  You should be using the `-ex` flag for exact matching.
- Unless you have a very old Expect/Tcl installed, the five [lindex $argv *] lines can be condensed into `lassign $argv loginuser loginpass ipaddr remote_dir put_file`.
- Expect has its own `sleep` function so you don't need `exec sleep 1` just `sleep 1`.
- Rather than duplicating the password handling, when you match `"Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"` change the handler to

> ```
> {
>     send "yes\r"
>     exp_continue
> }
> ```

to restart the same expect command.